# Find most recent authors

Tags: posts, loop, author

What I'm looking to do it get the 16 latest posts from 16 different authors. In other words there would be the 16 latest posts, but no one single author would have more that 1 post on the page.

The way I've thought about doing it, is looping through all the authors, removing the duplicates, then limited that to 16 and use that to generate the posts in a for each loop, but I'd imagine that would be heavy on the server.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a custom SQL query to grab the latest 16 post IDs with unique authors;

```
$post_IDs = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'product' AND post_status = 'publish' GROUP BY post_author ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 16" );
```

Then start up a new query with the `post__in` argument;

```
$recent_posts = new WP_Query( array( 'post__in' => $post_IDs, 'post_type' => 'product' ) );
```

Comment: I think its almost there, the results also need to be from a custom post type "product," but I'm having trouble when I edited the query.

'code'
$post_IDs = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts GROUP BY post_author WHERE post_type = 'product' ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 16" );
'code'

thoughts?

Comment: UPDATE:

Moved the WHERE before the GROUP and its working in PHPMyAdmin, but not on the site:

$post_IDs = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'product' GROUP BY post_author ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 14" );
   $args = array(
    'post__in' => $post_IDs
   );

Comment: Update:

Got it I just could use the post__in, I had to use a for each loop for each of the IDs. thanks.

Comment: @philmadelphia I wouldn't advise querying in a loop - that'll be 40+ database queries! You also need to add the `post_type` arg in your query call too - see revised answer.