# Latest 5 post excerpts from 5 different authors in Sidebar

Tags: query-posts, sidebar, list-authors

I'm attempting to display the latest 5 post excerpts from 5 different authors in my blog sidebar. Below is the code I'm using which I tweaked from this thread: [Find most recent authors](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19884/find-most-recent-authors)

So far, I've gotten it to work however rather than display each individual author's most recent post, it's showing the author's earliest post. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong? I've been struggling w/ this for a few days so appreciate any direction you can give. I'm a newbie to PHP but can understand enough to tweak code. Thanks!! You can see it working on my site: [wearestd.com](http://wearestd.com)

```
<?php
global $wpdb;

$post_IDs = $wpdb->get_col( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE post_type = 'post' AND post_status = 'publish' GROUP BY post_author ORDER BY post_date DESC LIMIT 5" );

$my_query = new WP_Query( array( 'post__in' => $post_IDs) );

if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
<?php userphoto_the_author_thumbnail() ?>
<div id="author_excerpt"><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4><br />
<?php the_advanced_excerpt('length=50'); ?></a>
<?
endwhile;
}
?>
```

Comment: try changing `DESC` to `ASC` in the sql query.

Comment: I tried that, same results

Answer (score 0):

Think I've figured it out. Here's the code I used courtesy of [this thread](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/latest-5-authors-sorted-by-posting-data) on the WP Support Forum. Just replace (`)<?php the_author_posts_link(); ?>(`) 
with whatever excerpt code you want to use. And Voila!

```
<?php
//list 5 latest authors
$authors =  array();
$count = 0;
$args=array(
'post_type' => 'post',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'caller_get_posts'=> 1
);
$my_query = null;
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
while ($my_query->have_posts() && $count < 5) : $my_query->the_post();
$author_id=$my_query->post->post_author;
if (!in_array($author_id,$authors)) { ?>
<?php the_author_posts_link(); ?>
<?php $count++;
$authors[]=$author_id;
}
endwhile;
}
wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data stomped by the_post().
?>
```